# JAVA: After adding all dependent jars to -cp, still getting errors

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, lucene, classpath

I'm working on a project(on Linux) with Lucene, and it works just fine in Eclipse after adding all external jars to build path. However, when I tried to compile them manually I got this error:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardAnalyzer
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
```

Here are the external jars I'm using in Eclipse:

[image]

I already tried these:

(java -cp "jar1:jar2..." class-built-in-eclipse)

```
java -cp "../../lucene-4.0.0/core/lucene-core-4.0.0.jar:../../lucene-4.0.0/queryparser/lucene-queryparser-4.0.0.jar:../../lucene-4.0.0/queries/lucene-queries-4.0.0.jar:../../lucene-4.0.0/analysis/common:../../IK Analyzer 2012FF_hf1/IKAnalyzer2012FF_u1.jar:." MyIndex
```

(java -cp jar1:jar2...:"the one that has whitespace in its path" class-built-in-eclipse)

```
java -cp ../../lucene-4.0.0/core/lucene-core-4.0.0.jar:../../lucene-4.0.0/queryparser/lucene-queryparser-4.0.0.jar:../../lucene-4.0.0/queries/lucene-queries-4.0.0.jar:../../lucene-4.0.0/analysis/common:"../../IK Analyzer 2012FF_hf1/IKAnalyzer2012FF_u1.jar":. MyIndex
```

and (moving the dependent jars to the same folder as the class file)

```
java -cp . MyIndex
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the dependencies (your jar files) into a single folder (say `lib`), then you can use something like

```
java -cp "lib/*":. MyIndex
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! But I'm still curious why it didn't work in my examples. Could you kindly explain?

Comment: It's hard to say without access to the machine itself, you were missing a jar (or you got the path slightly wrong to one). That's the first thing I would examine.